# How do you install MySQL 5.1 on Ubuntu 8.10?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-8.10

According to various blogs and forums, you should be able to do simply "sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1".

But I tried and it doesn't work (package not found by this name). What am I missing?

Comment: Ubuntu 8.10 only comes with MySQL 5.0. Either upgrade Ubuntu to at least 9.04, find a third part repository that has 5.1 or install from source or binary .tgz.

Answer (score 5):

There's a group at dotdeb.org - they maintain a MySQL 5.1 package for Debian that you might try.

First, add the following line to your /etc/apt/sources.list

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org lenny all
```

Then refresh your local list of packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now you can install the package:

```
apt-get install mysql-server-5.1
```

If you have a version of /etc/mysql/my.cnf that you have edited, the install will ask you if you want it replaced. I replaced it and made a note to fix the --bind-address = 127.0.0.1 line to the server's ip addr so I can connect over the network.

Answer (score 0):

download it from the site, and follow instruction.
it works.

Downlaod:
[link text](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/5.1.html#downloads)

Instructions:
[link text](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-linuxunix-excerpt/5.1/en/index.html)

Comment: This doesn't work. Even after full build and "make install", it's somehow incomplete, lacks integration with the rest of the OS - no startup scripts, etc.

Comment: what error do you get ? did you follow the install instruction on the site ? this should work on any linux edition.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Administration Synaptic Package Manager and search for MySql. You will be able to see mysql-server and the version is 5.1.3.

If you do a 'sudo apt-get install mysql' it will Mysq 5.1.3, you can also try and install 'sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1'

While you are there you can also install modules/drivers for your fav language.

Comment: Actually no, "sudo apt-get install mysql" installs 5.0.67 not 5.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a inofficial repository. See this Ubuntu Forums post: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1039946&highlight=mysql+5.1

Comment: the post recommends adding this to /etc/apt/sources.list:

deb http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org stable all

browsing to those URLS shows a mysql-dfsg-5.1,
but apt-get install mysql-dfsg-5.1 doesn't work.

root@dbtest:~# apt-get install mysql-dfsg-5.1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Couldn't find package mysql-dfsg-5.1

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` beforehand? If you change your sources.list, you'll need to update the package cache.